# Can Goland autocomplete SQL statements using other SQL packages?

Tags: sql, go, autocomplete, goland

Goland is great at auto-completing SQL statements if I use the `sql.DB` package functions.

For example, Goland will provide SQL autocompletion (including DDL data) in this setting:

```
result, err := someDB.Exec(`INSERT INTO <cursor here>`)
```

Can I configure Goland to show me SQL autocompletion in other contexts? For instance, I'm using [`github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) and it has functions of the form:

```
err := someDB.Get(&user, `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="%s"`, email)
```

In this second example, autocompletion wasn't triggered.

I can't find where/if this is configured in the Goland settings. Can I tell Goland which function parameters should be eligible for SQL autocompletion?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Alt + Enter` inside the query and then use `Inject Language` and start typing the SQL dialect that you want to insert.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Is there any way to tell Goland to do this by default?

Comment: It should recognize the sqlx package automatically, but I guess there might be some bugs. I'll follow this with an issue to check why this happens, sorry for the inconvenience.

As a workaround, you can use a comment above the string with something like this `//language=SQL` in order to keep the injection across restarts/IDE users.

Comment: Thanks again. I used `//language=PostgreSQL` in a comment above and it worked fine (upon re-opening the file).

Comment: Could you provide a link to the issue you created, assuming it's in a public tracker?